# jetty metrics (e.g. queue length)

Tags: jetty

Is there a way to get the metrics for Jetty server, for example, the queue length, processing time, etc.

I looked at the QueuedThreadPool class, and tracked the the calling chain for getQueueSize, but I didn't find it got exposed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"Queue Length" is a very vague term and can apply to many many different things.

As for seeing the metrics for Jetty, enable JMX, restart your server, and take a look.

Goto your `${jetty.base}` and add the `jmx` module.

```
$ cd /path/to/mybase
$ java -jar /path/to/jetty-dist/start.jar --add-to-start=jmx
```

Once you have restarted, use the `jmc` command that comes with your JDK (or if you are using an ancient JDK use `jconsole`) and attach to the running Jetty process to see the various things exposed by Jetty for monitoring.